# What's the probability that B will catch 3 fish before A catches 3 fish

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution, poisson-process

This is a basic question, but I do not completely understand.

> A and B are both catching fish at times of independent poisson processes with rates $1$ and $2$ respectively. What is the probability B catches $3$ fish before A catches $3$ fish?

The correct solution is to compute the probability that B will catch 3 out of first 5 fish, 4 out of first 5 fish, or 5 out of first 5 fish. This $5$ comes from $3+3-1$. (using binomial distribution)

I don't understand why we need to consider first 5. Also, why we need to consider the case where B will catch 4 and 5 fish? Why we do not need to consider the probability of the sixth fish.

On the exam, I consider the probability that B will catch 3 out of first 6 fish. This is not correct. Could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: If it helps, this is equivalent to a best three-out-of-five series of games.

Comment: @BrianTung I just could not understand why they are equivalent.

Comment: Note that you can write sequences of who caught the first, second, third, etc. fish as follows: ABBAB means A caught the first fish, then B caught the second and third fish, then A caught the fourth fish, and lastly B caught the fifth fish, which was their third fish, which means that they "won."  There are only $2^5 = 32$ distinct sequences of five fish, so you should have no problem writing them all down.  Is the question of who first caught three fish ever undecided at the end of any of those sequences?

Comment: Note that we will include sequences such as BBBAB, in which B catches their third fish after only three fish.  In such a case, the fourth and fifth fish are unnecessary information, but at any rate, they do not *contradict* the result of the first three fish.  Without fail, whoever is ahead after five fish was the first to three fish; it is impossible for both A and B to have caught three fish after only five fish, and one of them is sure to.  (After four fish, if neither has caught three fish, then they must be tied 2 to 2, and the very next fish must decide the "winner.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B had $2$ fish and caught the last fish (#$6$), then A already won, since he had $5-2 = 3$ fish beforehand. Thus, B could never be "first" in this scenario.

Alternatively, note that someone will get their $3$rd after $5$ fish since $5/2 = 2.5 > 2$ and the Pigeonhole principle applies.

Comment: In "$5/2=2.5$," does "$2$" come from "$2$ persons"? Could you elaborate on why someone will get his third fish after 5 fish?

Comment: @JamesWang Suppose that both people haven't reached 3 fish yet after 5 fish were caught. Then each person has at most 2 fish for a maximum total of 4, which contradicts the fact that the total is 5.